# Getting syntax error when trying to fetch records after 12th row in MS Access- offset SQL query syntax error

Tags: ms-access, syntax-error

```
SELECT * 
FROM Facesheet 
ORDER BY ID OFFSET 12 ROWS ;
```

I'm trying fetch the records after the 12th row.

When I run this query in MS Access, I get a syntax error.

Comment: Simple Google search will tell you Access does not recognize Offset.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Access does not recognize Offset.

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM Facesheet WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 12 ID FROM Facesheet) ORDER BY ID;`